# Changing the output directory of a vbs script

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a script that what it does is you place the file into a folder and then it automatically converts the file into a tab deliminited file. It then creates a new folder called "output". What I need to do is to be able to save it to a specified location. Below is a copy of the code I have written.

```
Dim saveDirBase

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

set top = fso.GetFolder(shell.CurrentDirectory)
saveDirBase = top & "\" & "output"

Sub TraverseFolders(path)
set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

XL2Tab(folder)

For each item in folder.SubFolders
If item.Path <> saveDirBase Then
Call TraverseFolders(item.Path)
End If
Next
set folder = Nothing
End Sub

Sub XL2Tab(folder)
Dim saveDir
set files = folder.Files

If folder.Name <> top.Name Then
saveDir = saveDirBase & "\" & folder.Name
Else
saveDir = saveDirBase
End If

If fso.FolderExists(saveDir) = False Then
fso.CreateFolder(saveDir)   
End If

For each file In files
If file.Name <> Wscript.ScriptName Then
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(folder.Path & "\" & file.Name)   
objWorkbook.SaveAs saveDir & "\" & file.Name & ".txt", -4158    
objWorkbook.close
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next
End Sub

If fso.FolderExists(saveDirBase) = False Then
fso.CreateFolder(saveDirBase)   
End If

Call TraverseFolders(top)
```

Comment: Supposedly, you mean a location other than "output"? How exactly is this location specified? user input? configuration file? registry key?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to prompt the user for an output folder, the simplest way to request user input would be an [`InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5):

```
top = InputBox("Enter base folder.", WScript.ScriptName)
```

That's going to require some input validation, though:

```
If IsEmpty(top) Then
  WScript.Echo "User pressed [Cancel]."
  WScript.Quit 1
ElseIf top = "" Then
  WScript.Echo "Empty path."
  WScript.Quit 1
ElseIf Not fso.FolderExists(top) Then
  WScript.Echo top & " doesn't exist. Creating ..."
  fso.CreateFolder(top)
End If
...
```

A better way would be using the [`Shell.BrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774065) method:

```
Set os = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
basedir = os.Namespace("C:\").Self.Path
Set fldr = os.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder:", &h10&, basedir)

If fldr Is Nothing Then
  WScript.Echo "User pressed [Cancel]."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

top = fldr.Self.Path
...
```

Comment: What would need to be done is for it to go to from one network share to another share folder. This would need to be an automated task and it would also need to be able to see the newest file.

Comment: What do you mean by "go from one network share to another share folder"? What do you mean by "see the newest file"? Please update your question with a more detailed description of what you want the script to do.